# 'UIImage' does not have a member named 'element'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to make an app that uses 6 UIImage Views to display the six sides of a die.  I am trying to store the 6 pictures in an array but I am getting the error "'UIImage' does not have a member named 'element'"

Here is the function I created for the dice:

```
func dice() {
    var diceImages: [UIImage] //declares diceImages as a UIImage
    for i in 1...6 {
        diceImages[i-1] = [UIImage(named: "dice-\(i).png")] //adds the images to diceImages
    }
    diceOne.image = diceImages[0] //sets the image for the first Image View
    //I will set the others here but I wanted to fix my error up there first
}
```

I do not have anything named element here and previously I created an array of images for an animation but using a slightly different method (a bad method but it worked):

```
var backGndImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "AppTexture-1.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-2.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-3.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-4.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-5.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-6.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-7.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-8.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-9.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-10.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-11.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-12.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-13.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-14.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-15.png")!, UIImage(named: "AppTexture-16.png")!]
```

If there is a better way to do what I've done here other than the method to fix the error please let me know; I am very new to programming apps, and swift, as I'm sure many may be.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Is Xcode showing you an error before you build, or does the app crash and show this error?

Comment: Quote the EXACT and COMPLETE error message.

Comment: I did quote the exact and complete error message Hot Licks, the error is showing up on diceImages[i-1] = [UIImage(named: "dice-\(i).png")] before I built the program.

Comment: You haven't initialised your array, you've only declared it. And you're trying it insert arrays of images into an array that take images (not arrays of images).

Comment: What do you mean initialize it?  My other array worked fine with only a declaration if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
func dice() {
  var diceImages: [UIImage] = []
  for i in 1...6 {
    diceImages.append(UIImage(named: "dice-\(i).png"))
  }
  diceOne.image = diceImages[0]
}
```

Your other array worked fine because you declared it, and gave it a value. Your `diceImages` array was only a declaration - you didn't actually create an array.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked.  From now on I will also remember to use append.

Comment: Great that it works for you - would you mind accepting the answer if it does the job? You'll only want to use append if you want to add items to an existing `var` array, you can't append to an array declared with `let`.